# How producer know the outcome for AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm thinking of using SQS to handle a large data push from one service to another, using lambda function as a consumer. The problem is that producer want to know the outcome from lambda and whether all messages in SQS is processed.

Comment: Generally you use a dead letter queue and only worry about the failures.  Do you need an acknowledge of every message?

Comment: You could create an SNS topic that the producer subscribes to, and have your Lambda function send a message to that topic indicating the unique ID (or other correlator) of the message processed by the Lambda.

Comment: @stdunbar Yes i need each message feedback.

Comment: @jarmod Here the producer is api running on elastic beanstalk. Is it possible for beanstalk to register to SNS topic? ignore if i sound dumb.

Comment: As @jarmod said an SNS topic back would work or an "acknowledgement" queue.  But now what if you miss a message in the "acknowledgement" queue?  Or miss a message from SNS?  If you create an asynchronous architecture you need to figure out how you'll deal with these things.

Comment: If you need a definitive way to track each message, it might be better to use a persistent data store (a database) rather than a queue. That way, you can determine the status of each 'message' at any time.